# IMFSinkWriter::BeginWriting does not initialize because the IMFMediaEventGenerator has pending events

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to use the IMFSinkWriter to render audio samples(IMFSample), but I have problems when calling the `IMFSinkWriter::BeginWriting` method because it returns the code: `MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS`. This occurs because I am calling the `IMFStreamSink::BeginGetEvent(Callback, null)`.

I tried calling the method (BeginWriting) without first calling (BeginGetEvent), surprise, the method works correctly and I can process audio samples successfully.

The problem is that I can not make calls to (BeginGetEvent) after the SinkWriter has been created.

The code that you use to create the SAR (Stream Audio Render):

```
HRESULT Hr = E_FAIL;
IMFMediaSink *pAudioRender = NULL;
IMFStreamSink *pStreamSink = NULL;
IMFMediaTypeHandler *pMediaHandler = NULL;
IMFPresentationClock *pPresentClock = NULL;
IMFPresentationTimeSource* pTimeSource = NULL;
IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;

Hr = MFCreateAudioRenderer(NULL, &pAudioRender);
```

I create the IMFPresenetationClock for Collector:

```
Hr = MFCreateSystemTimeSource(&pTimeSource);
Hr = MFCreatePresentationClock(&pPresentClock);
pPresentClock ->SetTimeSource(pTimeSource);
IMFMediaSink->SetPresentationClock(pPresentClock );
```

This part I configure the Stream Sink:

```
pAudioRender->GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, &pStreamSink);
pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pMediaHandler);
pMediaHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(DecodePCM);
```

If I call BeginGetEvent here, SinkWriter will not be created. If I call after creating SinkWriter, I get success, but I can not use BeginGetEvent again because it will return me: MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS.

I used this code to create the SinkWriter, the creation happens well, but on the third line, I get an error code if I call (BeginGetEvent) in IMFStreamSink.

```
Hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(pAudioRender, NULL, &pSinkWriter);
pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(DecodePCM);
pSinkWriter->BeginWriting(); //HR -> MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS
```

I want to use the `IMFMediaEventGenerator` of the `IMFStreamSink` interface to receive the events (MEStreamSinkRequestSample) to call the `IMFSourceReader::ReadSample` method.

For me to receive these events, I need to understand why `IMFSinkWriter::BeginWriting`, gets the event generator from `IMFStreamSink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to call `IMFMediaEventGenerator` methods in this case.

By using Sink Writer API you delegate management and exclusive control of Media Foundation primitive (SAR) to the Sink Writer instance. It is the subscriber for the events and there can be only one.

That is, if you want to process `MEStreamSinkRequestSample` yourself, you cannot use Sink Writer API.

There are similar questions on MSDN forums, e.g.

- [Why IMFMediaEventGenerator::GetEvent() always returns MF_E_MULTIPLE_SUBSCRIBERS?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d0040b54-83e0-434b-9284-2706953aedc0/why-imfmediaeventgeneratorgetevent-always-returns-mfemultiplesubscribers?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment)

Comment: Thank you for answering me. but I was a bit confused. How would I use IMFStreamSink :: ProcessSample then? This process only works with Video, for audio, I need SinkWriter to process. I would have to access the low-level APIs to render the audio then in this case CoreAudio? But what would SAR do then?
Or am I wrong here, and should I create a media source, be it custom or not, and use high-level api, MediaSession, as it appears in the Media Foundation framework?

Comment: There can be only one user of `ProcessSample`, which in your case Sink Writer is. You cannot work with the media/stream sink concurrently with another higher level consumer. If you are not okay with this, you have to stop using Sink Writer: manage the media sink your self handling entirely its operation, and in this case a part of your work will be related to sample processing, you will customizing it in the desired way. If Sink Writer owns the media sink you can't interfere.